# How to take a screenshot of HTML Node with clip-path CSS property? (html2canvas not working for this)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I'm using [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) library to take a screenshot of a HTML Node, but it simply doesnt recognize the `clip-path` property.

(i'm getting cross-origin issue trying to replicate the error here, so i made a jsfiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/1Ly9wn6k/

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="star-mask">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button>
```

```css
.star-mask {
  clip-path: path('m55,237 74-228 74,228L9,96h240');  
}

.square {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px
}
```

```js
function capture() {
  let node = document.querySelector('.star-mask')


  html2canvas(node)
    .then(canvas => {
      document.querySelector('#root').appendChild(canvas)
    })
}
```

Every time i click on "Capture" the canvas screenshot completely ignores the `clip-path` of the star shape and display only the red square. I already tried [html2image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library and got the same issue.

There is some other solution that can solve this issue? Or is currently impossible to capture the `clip-path` property using JavaScript?

Comment: This is currently not implemented yet so there is nothing you can do now to fix that with that library. Here is [the issue](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2016).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) works for me

```js
function capture() {
    let node = document.querySelector('.star-mask')

domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(dataUrl => {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    })
}
```

```css
.star-mask {
  clip-path: path('m55,237 74-228 74,228L9,96h240');  
}

.square {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div class="star-mask">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button>
```

Comment: This works for me. but the image isn't correct. The font-family does not apply.

Comment: @JacobRoberto Post a new question with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out html-to-image

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

htmlToImage.toPng(node)
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
  });
```

(from https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image).