# -webkit-mask-image is not working html2canvas render

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am trying to do template poster editor. I would like to add a image to my canvas while masking it. It works well, i can mask every photo that i want but when i try to render it, added image is rendered without any mask-image. How can i fix it?

This is my canvas

[image]

This is the result
[image]

Code:

```js
function capture() {
         $('#target').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {


               var a = document.createElement('a');
               a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
               name = document.getElementById("konukAdi").value
               name = name.replace(/\s/g, '')

               extname = document.getElementById("boyut-secimi").value
               a.download = name + extname + '.jpg';

               a.click();

            }
         });
      }
```

```css
top: 16.12%;
    left: 55.9%;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(/poster/images/masks/tercih.png)!important;
    z-index: 15;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 620px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
```

```html
<img src="" id="id_1" class="konukImg" onclick="dragImage(this);" style="mask-image: url(/poster/images/masks/tercih.png) !important; top:16.12%;left:55.9%; -webkit-mask-size:contain;-webkit-mask-image: url(/poster/images/masks/tercih.png)!important; ;z-index : 15;overflow : hidden; width:620px;height:auto; position : absolute;">
```

Comment: Do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288773/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-html-node-with-clip-path-css-property-html2canvas

Comment: It is not working at all. It gives resolution error, decrease quaility of my canvas. And also clip-path or mask is not working as well.

Comment: Hi, not sure what “it” you mean here. The SO question I pointed at has a couple of alternative libraries to try. Do neither of these work?

Comment: I mean solution in the link is not working at all. It causes the other problems in html2canvas. Even you can solve them, render quality is not good enough.

Comment: Which of the libraries did you try?

Comment: I solved the problem with using dom to image library and clip-path. Thanks for your help.